# Fullcalendar with bootstrap modal create multiple events

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

Here is my code

```
//event calendar
var eventCalendar = $("#event-calendar").fullCalendar({
    themeSystem: 'bootstrap4',
    editable: true,
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    defaultDate: $("#event-calendar").fullCalendar('today'),
    navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    events: '<?php echo base_url("admin/load-events");?>',
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    select: function(start, end, allDay){
        $('#insertEventModal').modal('show');
        var start = start.format("Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
        var end = end.format("Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
        $('#eventSaveBtn').on('click',function(){
            $('#eventSaveBtn').unbind('click');
            if($('#event_title').val() && $('#event_desc').val()){

                $('#insertEventModal').modal('hide');
                var title = $('#event_title').val();
                var desc = $('#event_desc').val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: '<?php echo base_url("admin/save-events");?>',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {title:title, desc:desc, start:start, end:end},
                    success: function (data) {
                        if(data){
                            eventCalendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                            alert("Event added successfully");
                        }else{
                            alert('Something went wrong when saving events!');
                        }

                    }
                });
            }else{
                alert("title or description can't be blank!");
            }
        });
        $('#insertEventModal').modal('destroy');
    },
    eventClick: function(event){
        $('#viewEventModal').modal('show');
        $('#viewEventModal #event_date').val(event.start.format("Do MMM Y HH:mm:ss"));
        $('#viewEventModal #event_title').val(event.title);
        $('#viewEventModal #event_desc').val(event.desc);
        var id = event.id;
        $('#eventDelBtn').on('click',function(){
            if(confirm('Are you sure you want to remove it?')){
                $('#eventDelBtn').unbind('click');
                $('#viewEventModal').modal('hide');
                $.ajax({
                    url: '<?php echo base_url("admin/del-events");?>',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {id:id},
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert("Event successfully deleted");
                        eventCalendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    },
    editable: true,
    eventResize: function (event){
        var start = event.start.format("Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
        var end = event.end.format("Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
        var id = event.id;
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo base_url("admin/update-events");?>',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {id:id, start:start, end:end},
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Event successfully updated");
                eventCalendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
            }
        });
    },
    eventDrop: function (event){
        var start = event.start.format("Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
        var end = event.end.format("Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
        var id = event.id;
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo base_url("admin/update-events");?>',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {id:id, start:start, end:end},
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Event successfully updated");
                eventCalendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I am using bootstrap modal. Whenever user click on a date it will open the modal, enter title and description and click save to store the event into the database. At that point it is working fine. But suppose I click on 24th August, then close the modal window with outenter anything and then click on 25th August and make an event by clicking on save button. It will ceate two events, at 24th August which I select but close the modal without saving anything, and at 25th August.

This is also with if I want to delete any events from there. For an example above event create task creates two events at 24th and 25th. If I click on 24th event a modal window will be open, if I cancel the window and again click on 25th Event and delete that event, the two events will be deleted.

I think whenever click on fullcalendar it store the selection, and if I cancel the modal window and click on other date, it stores the previous data. Now the question is how to unselect the date in which I dont want to create an event? 
I have tried with

```
eventCalendar.fullCalendar('unselect')
```

But it not working.

Comment: It's because you're binding multiple click events to your button. `$('#eventSaveBtn').on('click',function(){` runs every time the `select` function runs. It creates a brand new event handler every time, but it doesn't remove the previous one. So next time you click the button it runs all the event handlers attached to it. Hence it runs the previous insert again as well as the new one. Use `.off()` to remove previous handlers. http://api.jquery.com/off/

Comment: yes already solved it. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: if you already solved it then please remove the question